# Upgrade Schwinn 10 speed to Brifters

Tags: shimano, upgrades

I would like to upgrade my 1980 Schwinn Traveler 10 speed.  It presently has a Shimano 400 rear derailleur and Shimano FE(?) front derailleur.  I would like to install Brifters.  Is this a possibility and where could I find parts to do this.  Thank you!

Comment: Unless your Schwinn is gold plated or has exceptional sentimental value, what you ask is totally unwise economically.

Answer (score 5):

This is technically possible, but unreasonably expensive. It's not just a simple matter of replacing your brake levers. When your Schwinn was built, you could assemble a bike from parts *a la carte* and it would work. But modern (and by "modern" I mean "since about 1985") component groups are designed as systems, so if you get one part in the system, you need to make sure everything else on the bike is compatible with it.

You would need to start by taking your bike to a shop to have the rear triangle "cold set," because all modern drivetrains are built around longer rear axles than will fit in your frame: your frame has the dropouts spaced 126 mm apart, they would need to be 130 or 135 mm apart for a modern drivetrain (depending on what you get). Next you'll need the brifters, of course, new front and rear derailleurs (you could forego the front derailleur and go with a 1× setup), new cassette, and either a new rear wheel (and tire and tube) or your old wheel rebuilt with a new hub. You'll probably need new cranks and possibly a new bottom bracket. Plus new cables and cable housings.

You may be thinking "I might as well buy a new bike at that point." That indeed would be the better option, unless you have a strong emotional attachment to this particular frame and want to keep it on the road. A decent new or new-ish bike is dramatically better than your Schwinn, and can probably be had for about what you would spend buying all those parts retail.

Still want to give it a try? I should point out that there is a bike and bike-parts shortage worldwide because of the pandemic. And there are enough ways to get all this wrong that without a lot of research, you could easily wind up buying stuff that won't work together. It would be easier and more foolproof to let your local bike shop do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

I had a 1981 Raleigh which started life as a 5x2 with 630mm rims.

I received a donor bike which had a functional groupset and frame damage, so my parts costs was much reduced.  The

To get everything on the bike, I had to:

- shim between old 22mm bars and brifter clamp.
- clean and pick and file the steel BB threads to not destroy the new aluminium BB cartridge.  Fortunately it was a cartridge for threadded BBs
- cold-set (stretch) the rear triangle to take the wider wheel
- replace both the original Shimano 600 series brake calipers and the donor 105 calipers with brand new Tektro R559 long-reach calipers.  Even then the rear still didn't reach the rim, so I had to make a dropper/hanger plate.

Also I chose to:

- Replace all the inner and outer cables and bartape.
- Later, the low-spoke-count rear wheel kept breaking spokes, and with that few, one spoke put the whole thing enormously out of true.  I bought some used wheels, as per second picture.

[image: ""] 2017, on "completion"

[image: ""] 2019, with newer wheels, mudguards, etc set up for longer commute.

Eventually frame damage became worse, and the bike felt sketchy on downhills, so I had to retire the frame.

[image: Frame damaged] I knew it was like this, and had "straightened" the kink, but regular riding slowly made it worse.  I bought a used 90s frame and moved all the groupset over to that.

Was it worth doing?   Yes, for the learning experience.  I ended up with a sub-par road bike for cheap that was rideable, and as we all know, any bike beats no bike.

If I'd had to buy the groupset new?   No it would have been more effective to buy the new bike.